# Properly writing getters and setters with a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple object with getters and setters, I'm not entirely sure if the code for this is correct, I'm also a bit confused at the instances to use an underscore at. The current error I'm getting is `menu.addDishToCourses is not a function`  but console logging the meal, shows the property of it as a function. What gives?

```
let menu = {
    _courses: {
        _appetizer: [],
        _main: [],
        _dessert: [],

        get appetizers() {
            return this._courses.appetizer;
        },
        set appetizers(appetizerInput) {
          this._courses.appetizer = appetizerIn;
        },

        get mains() {
            return this._courses.main;
        },
        set mains(mainsInput) {
          this._courses.main = mainsInput;
        },

        get desserts() {
            return this._courses.dessert;
        },

        set desserts(dessertsInput) {
            this._courses.deseserts = dessertInput;
        },
        get courses() {
            return {
                appetizers: this._courses.appetizer,
                mains: this._courses.main,
                desserts: this._courses.dessert,
            };
        },

        addDishToCourses(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
            const dish = {
                name: dishName,
                price: dishPrice,
            };
            this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
        },

        getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
            const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
            const RandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
            return dishes[RandomIndex];
        },
        generateRandomMeal() {
            let appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizer');
            let main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('main');
            let dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('dessert');
            let totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;

            return `You order and appetizer ${appetizer.name},${main.name} and a main dish ${main.price} and a dessert ${dessert.price}. Total price was $${totalProice}. `;
        },
    }
};
menu.addDishToCourses('_appetizer', 'pepperoni', 5.43);
menu.addDishToCourses('_mains', 'steak', 18.0);
menu.addDishToCourses('_dessert', 'pie', 3.5);
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't my strong suit at all, but underscores are used for internal properties that your getters/setters map to. Haven't looked in depth yet, but the addDishToCourses seems to have _courses as a parent and not menu?

Comment: `menu` has one property, `_courses`. Everything else is defined as a member of that, so you need to be writing `menu._courses.....`. Also, the underscore is a convention that some people use to denote something that is private. It is not a requirement to use this convention. Lastly, to define a method, you actually need to create a property and assign a function to it, as in: `addDishToCourses:function(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. `this` in your getter and setter methods is referring `_courses` property of the `menu`, not the `menu` object itself.

You probably want to design your `menu` object similar to below:

```js
let menu = {
  _courses: {
    _appetizer: [],
    _main: [],
    _dessert: [],
    get appetizer() {
      return this._appetizer
    },
    get main() {
      return this._main
    },
    get dessert() {
      return this._dessert
    }
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this._courses.appetizer,
      main: this._courses.main,
      desserts: this._courses.dessert,
    };
  },
  addDishToCourses(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    let dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    //console.log(this._courses[courseName]);
    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  }
};


menu.addDishToCourses('_appetizer', 'pepperoni', 5.43);
menu.addDishToCourses('_main', 'steak', 18.0);
menu.addDishToCourses('_dessert', 'pie', 3.5);
console.log(menu.courses);
```

As far as underscore named properties go, it's just a JavaScript convention for naming private variables (since you'll be accessing those with public facing getter and setter methods). Putting the underscore doesn't actually *do* anything.

Comment: Thank you sir. The underscore confused me, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this setup `menu` has one property: `_courses`. `menu.addDishToCourses()` is not a function, but `menu._courses.addDishToCourses()` is.

I think you should take a step back and ask why you are using getters and setters rather than just accessing properties and functions. If the need for a getter or setter comes up, it should be obvious. If this gets much larger, it will be really tough to  maintain.

Having said that, if you want to continue with the current scheme, you just need to put the functions you want to call from `menu` on `menu`:

```js
let menu = {
  addDishToCourses(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  get appetizers() {
            return this._courses._appetizer;
   },
  _courses: {
    _appetizer: [],
    _main: [],
    _dessert: [],
  }
}

menu.addDishToCourses('_appetizer', 'pepperoni', 5.43);
console.log(menu.appetizers)
```

Comment: Bah, you beat me by a few seconds, haha. Should probably note that the underscores just note private fields/methods, and that in this case they're not really needed?

Answer (score 0):

A few quick points (some of which have been touched on in various comments):

1. Underscores are privacy by ***convention***, and do nothing to actually enforce privacy.  That state is ***still directly accessible*** to the menu users.
2. Using getters/setters with publicly accessible properties is futile in my opinion.  The purpose of getters/setters is to enforce a contract when accessing state, such that you could alter internal implementation details later without affecting users of your module.  If they can directly access and mutate your state then the getters/setters are just clutter because you have no way of knowing whether the module users have hewn to your implied privacy conventions.
3. There are ways of making your state private in JavaScript (see one option below).  However, if truly private state is not important then for the sake of clarity just drop the getters/setters and underscores.  Just make a plain object with some additional functions that add genuinely useful behavior for manipulating that state.

Now, if you really do want to keep your menu state private and control access to it here is an example of how you could do that.  To me this approach is cleaner, easier to read, and actually accomplishes what you intended.

```js
const menu = (function Menu() {
  // this state is privately scoped
  const courses = {
    appetizers: [],
    main: [],
    dessert: []
  };

  // these functions are privately scoped, unless revealed (see below)
  function addDish(course, name, price) {
    courses[course].push({ name, price });
  }

  function getDishesByCourse(course) {
    return courses[course];
  }

  // this is what you are revealing to the outside
  return { addDish, getDishesByCourse };
})();


menu.addDish('appetizers', 'pepperoni', 5.43);
console.log(menu.getDishesByCourse('appetizers'));
```